# Energy to matter and supersymmetric particle

Tags: nuclear-physics

Assuming the existence of supersymmetry could light be turned into matter?

I mean from energy we get a pair particle / antiparticle +  supersymmetric partner antiparticle of the supersymmetric partner in the term of particle reaction

$$ \gamma  \sim  a + anti(a)+ b + anti(b) $$

where 'a' is a particle and 'b' its supersymmetric partner.

Answer (score 0):

First some definitions:

A pair of particles means 1 particle + 1 antiparticle

A sparticle is a supersymmetric particle.

A (s)particle is either a particle or a supersymmetric particle.

One could imagine some rather complicated Feynman diagram which would turn 1 photon to the production of 2 pairs of (s)particles, like a scalar quantum electrodynamics vertex with one outgoing pair of sparticles that before finally leaving exchange a virtual photon which materializes in a   2-photon fusion process to another pair of normal particles or vice versa.

However, the production of a pair of (s)particles from a single real ($\neq$ virtual) photon is already kinematically impossible, because the momentum and energy of a real photon are strongly correlated by $E=c|\vec{p}|$ which makes the production of a (s)particle pair impossible. I guess, that this is also the case if both (s)particles on the way to leave exchange another photon which materializes in another pair of (s)particles. I also wonder if the latter would be kinematically possible.

Anyway, such a complicates process is not necessary to turn light into matter. Not possible for 1 real photon, but possible for 2 or 3 real photons.

2 (or even 3) real photons can if their total energy at least corresponds twice the rest mass of the (s)particles produce a pair, so turn light into (s)matter. Supersymmetry is not needed for this.

By the way if you have seen diagrams where a single turns into a pair of (s)particles, then note that the incoming photon can only be a virtual one.